# Create a dynamic SQL Where clause that both parts of the where statement are passed in parameters? i.e. Where Variable1 = Variable2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I have seen many examples of dynamic where clauses but none ever covered the issue I am having. Is it even possible?

```
Create Procedure ManualParse2
    (
        @Variable1 AS nvarchar(MAX) 
        ,@Variable2 AS nvarchar(MAX)
    )
AS
    Select * 
    From Faculty
    Where @Variable1
        Case
            When @Variable1 = 'Department' THEN Department
            When @Variable1 = 'Name' THEN Name
            When @Variable1 = 'Gender' THEN Gender
            When @Variable1 = 'FacultyID' THEN FacultyID
        END
        = @Variable2

EXEC ManualParse2 @Variable1 = 'Gender', @Variable2 = 'Male'
```

Comment: Does `@Variable1` always contain a valid field name ?

Comment: What does `WHERE @Variable1` mean? This dosen't look like dynamic SQL either, just "normal" boolean logic. The `WHERE` is somewhat pointless if you don't reference columns in your table though.

Comment: You also don't declare `@Variable` in your SP, only `@Variable1` and `@Variable1`; the latter of which you don't use. Is `@Variable` actually meant to be `@Variable2`. (*Note, those are actually parameters, not variables.*)

Comment: In this specific case @Variable1 will always contain a valid column name.

Comment: Which leads me to my question, @DanielSteck , what does `WHERE @Variable1` mean? Where `@Variable1` what..?

Comment: Secondly, 'Where @Variable1" Refers to a basic where statement in SQL i.e. "Where FacultyID = 001". I have been playing around with using case statements to solve my issue. After the end statement I tried just "= @Variable2"

Comment: Then why isn't the other half the the boolean expression there, @DanielSteck . For example `WHERE @Variable1 = '001'`?

Comment: *"In this specific case @Variable1 will always contain a valid column name"*. Then why declare the parameters as an `nvarchar(MAX)`? An object's name can at most contain 128 characters, not 1 Billion. Are there other cases?

Comment: Let me assume that, you try to generate a dynamic selection on the Faculty table. @Variabale1 specify the column name and the second one for the where condition value. The procedure returns the resultset of this dynamic select

Comment: The other half of the boolean is after the end statement "= @Variable2"  as for the nvarchar(max) was done more for future projects so I retain the habit if needed.

Comment: Check out the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c0b1/1 draft query

Comment: esat, you are correct in what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I am adding it to the answer if you check the SQLFiddle but this type of queries open to the SQL injections.

Comment: They don't have to be open to injection, @esat ; as I demonstrate in my answer. Only *poorly* written (Dynamic) SQL is open to injection.

Comment: You are right @Larnu, I mentioned about my query sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c0b1/1

Comment: Unfortunately you're link to the fiddle never loads, @esat , so i can only base on your deleted answer (which suffered significantly from injection).

Comment: Although you could use a `CASE` expression when all columns are of the same type (`WHERE CASE @Variable1 WHEN 'Department' THEN Department WHEN 'Name' THEN Name WHEN 'Gender' THEN Gender WHEN 'FacultyID' THEN FacultyID END = @Variable2`), dynamic SQL is the proper solution IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines, but I *suspect* what you actually want is:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ManualParse2 @ColumnName sysname, @ColumnValue nvarchar(50) AS --You aren't going to have a department with 1 billion characters in it
                                                                               --sysname is the correct data type for object names (it's a synonym for nvarchar(128) NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF + --This should reallty be a column list
               N'FROM dbo.Faculty' + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' = @ColumnValue;';

    --PRINT @SQL; --Unlikely to be needed for such a simple statement, but your debugging friend    
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ColumnValue nvarchar(50)', @ColumnValue;
END;
GO
```